# LayoutPanel with SimplePanel are not visible in browser

Tags: java, gwt

I am using following gwt code to experiment with LayoutPanel and SimplePanel componets of GWT, however when I run following example I see nothing in web page however when I inspect the webapge in bweoser (Chrome) I can navigate through the dom for all layout panels. Can anybody help me to indetify if there is any issue with code. I also have attached snaphot of chrome dom inspection UI for refernce.

```
package im.sma.gwt.samples.layoutpannels.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Unit;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.LayoutPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SimplePanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class Sma_LayoutPanels implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        SimplePanel west = new SimplePanel();
        SimplePanel east = new SimplePanel();
        SimplePanel middle = new SimplePanel();

        west.add(new Label("WEST"));
        east.add(new Label("EAST"));
        middle.add(new Label("Middle"));

        west.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("blue");
        east.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("pink");
        east.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("yellow");


        LayoutPanel holder = new LayoutPanel();
        holder.add(west);
        holder.add(east);
        holder.add(middle);

        holder.setWidgetLeftWidth(west, 0, Unit.PCT, 50, Unit.PCT);
        holder.setWidgetRightWidth(east, 0, Unit.PCT, 50, Unit.PCT);
        holder.setWidgetLeftRight(middle, 25, Unit.PCT, 25, Unit.PCT);
        holder.setWidgetTopBottom(middle, 25, Unit.PCT, 25, Unit.PCT);
        holder.forceLayout();

        RootPanel.get().add(holder);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I was using `RootPanel` instead of `RootLayoutPanel`, so replacing the last line with `RootLayoutPanel` solved the issue.

```
RootLayoutPanel.get().add(holder);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also use [SimpleLayoutPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimpleLayoutPanel.html) not [SimplePanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimplePanel.html) if you want predictable results. Layout panels implement ProvidesResize and RequiresResize interfaces that ensure that your layout will resize correctly.

Have a look to GWT documentation http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html